# How can i insert into Table1 where table2.column = value?

Tags: php, sql

I have a problem basically like the title, the query I have tried is:

```
INSERT INTO 
  pendingresults, 
  l1_afixtures (pendingresults.TeamAName, pendingresults.TeamA, 
pendingresults.TeamAScore, pendingresults.TeamBScore, pendingresults.TeamB) 
VALUES (
  '$pls', 
  '$TeamA', 
  '$TeamAScore', 
  '$TeamBScore', 
  '$TeamB') 
WHERE 
  l1_afixtures.team_name = $TeamA 
AND  
  l1_afixtures.fixture = $TeamB 
AND 
  l1_afixtures.disabled = 'enabled';
```

Is there anything wrong with this query, I know that the query without the

```
 where l1_afixtures.team_name = $TeamA AND  
 l1_afixtures.fixture = $TeamB AND l1_afixtures.disabled = 'enabled';
```

Works but with the where function i cant seem to get it working

Any ideas? thanks

Comment: What is pendingresults? I don't think you can do a JOIN with an insert like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try like this:

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (<columns>)
SELECT <columns>
FROM Table1
WHERE <condition>;
```

In this particular case it could be something like this:

```
INSERT INTO pendingresults (TeamAName, TeamA, TeamAScore, TeamBScore, TeamB) 
SELECT TeamAName, TeamA, TeamAScore, TeamBScore, TeamB
FROM l1_afixtures
WHERE 
    l1_afixtures.team_name = $TeamA 
    AND l1_afixtures.fixture = $TeamB 
    AND l1_afixtures.disabled = 'enabled'
```

Comment: If you don't limit the select result to 1, then it could insert the values multiple times.

Answer (score -2):

You can't do an `INSERT ... VALUES... WHERE`

You can do an `INSERT .... SELECT ... WHERE`

And you can only `INSERT` into one table at a time.

So

```
insert into pendingresults (TeamAName, TeamA, TeamAScore, TeamBScore, TeamB) 
values('$pls', '$TeamA', '$TeamAScore', '$TeamBScore', '$TeamB')
```

Or

```
insert into pendingresults (TeamAName, TeamA, TeamAScore, TeamBScore, TeamB) 
Select TeamAName, TeamA, TeamAScore, TeamBScore, TeamB
from l1_afixtures
where 
    l1_afixtures.team_name = $TeamA 
    AND l1_afixtures.fixture = $TeamB 
    AND l1_afixtures.disabled = 'enabled'
```

Comment: So it isnt possible to do what im trying todo?

Comment: you can't. Insert..Select is the best way.

Comment: If you don't limit the select result to 1, then it could insert the values multiple times.

Comment: @JustinSatyr That's making a lot of assumption about an unknown dataset.

Comment: No, all that means if that if `team_name`, `fixture`, and `disable` values match for multiple rows, the data would be inserted multiple times. It's best practice to assume that duplicates *might* exist no matter what validation the webpage might use (which isn't shown here, anyway).

Comment: I do not understand this one, what does it insert and why does it select Select TeamAName, TeamA, TeamAScore, TeamBScore, TeamB
from l1_afixtures when l1_afixtures contains team_name, fixture and disabled

Comment: @user1626410 You haven't told us what your tables contain!

Comment: l1_afixtures.team_name = $TeamA 
AND  
  l1_afixtures.fixture = $TeamB 
AND 
  l1_afixtures.disabled = 'enabled';
shows that l1_afixtures contains disabled, fixture and team_name and  l1_afixtures (pendingresults.TeamAName, pendingresults.TeamA, 
pendingresults.TeamAScore, pendingresults.TeamBScore, pendingresults.TeamB)  shows what pendingresults table contains